# What is the difference between SSH and HTTP?

Tags: protocols

What is the difference between SSH and HTTP and how are they related to each other?

Comment: This link might help- https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both ssh and HTTP are protocols to communicate between client and server.Following are the basic difference between SSH and HTTP.

SSH means “Secure Shell”. It has a built-in username/password authentication system to establish a connection. It uses Port 22 to perform the negotiation or authentication process for connection. Authentication of the remote system is done by the use of public-key cryptography and if necessary, it allows the remote computer to authenticate users.

HTTP means HyperText Transfer Protocol. HTTP is the underlying protocol used by the World Wide Web and this protocol defines how messages are formatted and transmitted, and what actions Web servers and browsers should take in response to various commands.

Hope it will give you basic understanding on this.

Comment: a key point missing here is that SSH is stateful while HTTP is stateless